# How to insert data into database using Java API?

Tags: java, api, jdbc

I am trying to insert data into database using the below code but something is not working correctly. It runs without error but it does not insert anything into the database.

```
public Map<String,String> createuser(String handle, String password, String fullname, String location, String xmail, String bdate)
    {
        Map<String,String> userIdMap = new HashMap<>();
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;

        try
        {
            Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
            String queryString = null;
            queryString = "INSERT INTO Identity(handle, password, fullname, location, xmail, bdate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";


            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(queryString);
            stmt.setString(1, handle);
            stmt.setString(2, password);
            stmt.setString(3, fullname);
            stmt.setString(4, location);
            stmt.setString(5, xmail);
            stmt.setString(6, bdate);

            userIdMap.put(handle, password);
            userIdMap.put(fullname, location);
            userIdMap.put(xmail, bdate);
            int s = stmt.executeUpdate(queryString);

            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return userIdMap;
    } // createuser()
```

Possible error message

```
<html><head><title>Grizzly 2.3.23</title><style><!--div.header {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#003300;font-size:22px;-moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;border-top-left-radius: 10px;-moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;border-top-right-radius: 10px;padding-left: 5px}div.body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:#FFFFCC;font-size:16px;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px}div.footer {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#666633;font-size:14px;-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;padding-left: 5px}BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;}B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;}A {color : black;}HR {color : #999966;}--></style> </head><body><div class="header">Request failed.</div><div class="body">Request failed.</div><div class="footer">Grizzly 2.3.23</div></body></html>
```

Comment: Did you set auto commit to false ?

Comment: Unrelated, but you have a strange way of using maps.

Comment: What is the value of s?

Comment: Call method [`getAutoCommit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getAutoCommit--) on `conn`. Does it return **true** ? Also, method [`executeUpdate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate--) returns the number of rows affected. In other words, in your example, it should return 1 (one). Does it?

Comment: @CodeScale Do I set auto commit to true or false? I just set it to true.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Would you suggest a better way to use maps or does it not really matter?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen The value of s should return 1 since that is the number of rows affected.

Comment: @TommyNorth ok and it works now?

Comment: @TommyNorth I'm just wondering what's the point of associating a name with a location or a mail address with a birthday. Why a map and not a proper class that describes a user?

Comment: @CodeScale No still not working and it is outputting something do not know if it is an error message or not, I will update my question with what is outputted to terminal.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at your server's log, since you're printing a stacktrace and doing nothing else in case an exception is thrown. Chances are your stderr is caught by your server and gets sent to a log. In other words it seems that "It runs without error" because you're *ignoring* any error.

Comment: @tommy yes. Does it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having us follow you on a journey to go find where your stack trace is getting logged, just add this into your catch block. This is going to be the fastest path right now to actually showing you your error message.

```
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      System.out.format("SQL State: %s\n%s\n", e.getSQLState(), e.getMessage());
    ...
    ...
    }
```